# I have checked value but how can I check this against a question?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the value for a radio button and I want to check this against a question's answer.

I am using an array of questions and also have the previous and next buttons set up to cycle through questions.

I have read thisabout input (if someone finds helful): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

I will add a snippet.

I have tried various syntax

```
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", check);

const answeTo = arrayQuestion[i].answer;

function check(anwserTo) {

    var type = document.getElementsByName('rad');

    //Checks which button is selected
    if (type.checked == anwserTo) {
        alert('Well Done');
}}
```

Here I tired to store the value in a const and then check the answer against the current question:

```
const answeTo = arrayQuestion[i].answer;

function check(anwserTo) {

    var type = document.getElementsByName('rad');
    //Storing the value
    var answer = type.checked;
    //Checks which button is selected
    if (answer == anwserTo) {
    alert('Well Done');
}};
```

This is a broken down version of what I am working with (Snippet of full cod e below)

```
<js>
//Question constructor and example question
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    };

//Stored in a array with others
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'B');


//Function to check if the value of the radio button is correct


const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", check);
const answeTo = arrayQuestion[i].answer;

function check(anwserTo) {

    var type = document.getElementsByName('rad');
    var answer = type.checked;
    //Checks which button is selected
    if (answer == anwserTo) {
        alert('Well Done');
    }


};
```

The result should just alert that the question was answered correctly.

I have been getting no errors.

```js
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    };

    checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
        if (ansSelected === answer) {
            console.log('Well Done')
        };
    };
};

//Questions
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'B');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?', '1', '4', '6', '5', 'C');
var questionThree = new Question('Where was the first Godfather in the mafia from?', 'Milan', 'Gunoa', 'Rome', 'Napoli', 'D');

//Index of the array with the questions array 
var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];
const arrayAns = [questionOne.answer, questionTwo.answer];

//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;



const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", check);

const answeTo = arrayQuestion[i].answer;

function check(anwserTo) {

    var type = document.getElementsByName('rad');
    var answer = type.checked;
    //Checks which button is selected
    if (answer == anwserTo) {
        alert('Well Done');
    }


};






//Next button which cycles through the array and show the current question.
//With if statement to catch out of bound error
const n = document.getElementById('next');
n.addEventListener("click", next);

function next() {

    i++;

    if (i === arrayQuestion.length) {
        i = 0;
    };

    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;

};


//Function to go back to previouse question
//With if statement to catch out of bound error
const p = document.getElementById('previous')
p.addEventListener("click", prev)

function prev() {

    i--;

    if (i === -1) {
        i = arrayQuestion.length - 1;
    };


    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;


};
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 200;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formEl">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>
            
            <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value='A'>
            <label for="rad1" id="rad1Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value='B'>
            <label for="rad2" id="rad2Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value='C'>
            <label for="rad3" id="rad3Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value='D'>
            <label for="rad4" id="rad4Label"></label>

            <button id="previous" type="button" class="userSelection">Previous</button>
            
            <button id="next" type="button" class="userSelection">Next</button>
            
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
    <script src = js/app.js></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here.

First, you're using the function `check(anwserTo)` as the callback for the `click` event listener, however, you're expecting the answer to the question as the parameter for that function but the event listener is providing an `event` object to it. So you need to somehow give your function a way of knowing what the answer to the current question is so it can check against the user input.

Secondly, inside the body of that same function you're getting the data of all the radio buttons with `var type = document.getElementsByName('rad');` but this returns an array so the following line `var answer = type.checked;` will not return what you're expecting. Instead you should iterate through the array of elements, find which one of the radio buttons is checked and store it in some variable so you can finally test it against the answer to the current question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this that you want?

```html
<p>How much is 1 + 1?</p>

<input type="radio" name="group-1" onclick="test(this)" value="1">
<label for="ans-1">1</label>

<input type="radio" name="group-1" onclick="test(this)" value="2">
<label for="ans-2">2</label>

<input type="radio" name="group-1" onclick="test(this)" value="3">
<label for="ans-3">3</label>

<script>
  const correctAnswer = 2
  
  const test = (element) => {
    if(element.value == correctAnswer) {
      alert("Right answer!")
    } else {
      alert("Wrong answer!")
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes but with mutable questions :)